# Is the normal distribution a better approximation to the binomial distribution with proportions near or far from 0.5?

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, normalization

[From the Online Stat Book:](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/normal_distribution/normal_approx.html)

> [image]

I don't understand this:

> The accuracy of the approximation depends on the values of N and π. A rule of thumb is that the approximation is good if both Nπ and N(1-π) are both greater than 10.

Let's assume I have an unfair coin, so I get heads with a probability of 0.2. So what? I still can find the mean of the distribution, the SD. I next can find the Z-scores, and then use the normal calculator. Why would the returned probability be less accurate?

Comment: What is not clear to me is what n and N are.  My presumption is that n is the sample size and N would be the population size but this is a problem involving an infinite population.  But on the other hand it looks like N and p are the parameters of the binomial distribution. The point of the question relates only to the normal approximation and the sample estimate of p, So consider the sample estimate of p from a sample of size N and calculate its variance when the true parameter is  .2 and when it is .5. Which one has the smaller variance. It does not require a simulation to answer it.

Comment: But if you do a simulation with p=.2 and N=10 and look at the histogram from repeating the process say 1000 times and do the same for p=.5 you can visually compare the histograms and see which one looks closer to a normal distribution.

Comment: @MichaelChernick - I have no Java enabled in my Chrome browser. It looks like this language is not much used nowadays (I'm not that computer savvy, but it looks so to me)..

Comment: @MichaelChernick - I found [this page that explained the issue to me](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/book/export/html/70)

Comment: Those histograms tell the story and maybe better than my words.

Comment: Note that the screen capture makes the Greek letter pi look like an "n."

Comment: I agree, what looks like an $n$ is actually a $\pi$ (representing a population proportion). One widely used computer typeface ("font") makes them almost indistinguishable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NOTE: Following up on @whuber's comment, I realized that I was imposing aesthetic constraints on the plotting of the values in terms of the `breaks` options in `hist()`. Running the same simulation with the same seed, a symmetrical illustration is now generated. I believe this addresses the issue.

---

You may want to refer to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/176428/67822) by Glen_b.

This would be the shape of the simulation:

[image]

I ran $100,000$ simulations of random values extracted from a binomial distribution of $10$ trials with a probability of success of the individual Bernoulli experiments of $0.2$, $0.5$ and $0.8$, respectively. Clearly $p=0.5$ approaches a normal distribution much closer, and the more extreme probability values result in markedly skewed distributions.

Comment: I would just tend to think of the "empirical probability" $\hat{p}=n/N$. This will always equal $p$ in expectation, and it makes it clearer that 0.5 will be the symmetric and "least constrained" case, whereas higher/lower values will tend to have a skewed PDF that will "hit the wall" at right/left (i.e. 1 or 0).

Comment: This is an insightful reply (+1).  Unfortunately the figure is suspect: the histogram for $p=0.5$ is shifted one-half unit to the left of where it should be, causing a mismatch between it and the plot of the approximating Normal density (which is correctly centered at $0.5$).  The histograms for $p=0.2$ and $p=0.8$ are not mirror images of each other, but they ought to be (and their approximating Normal density plots *are* mirror images).  Since you are relying on the figure for your demonstration, it is important to make it accurate.  Consider drawing barplots of the Binomial probabilities.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that ultimately it's the cdf we are using when we approximate (such as to get a tail area for example).  That's not to suggest there's something wrong with this approach, especially for visualization purposes (it's got a long pedigree, for sure going right back to the earliest days). Ultimately one must judge the quality of the approximation for ones own particular purposes by seeing how it behaves; rules of thumb are generally either too strict or not strict enough. They can be a starting point for an investigation of the approximation in some particular instance.

Answer (score 3):

The rule of thumb says that both $N\pi $ and $N(1-\pi)$ should be $>10$. For $\pi=.5$ this demands $N>20$. But for $\pi=0.2$ (as well as for $\pi=0.8$) it demands $N>50$. So we see that the "approximability" kicks in a lot earlier when $p=.5$.